# Drag and drop issue in Chrome related to Windows scale (125%)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I have an issue with drag and drop on Chrome (v69.0.3497.100). Specifically, some of the drag and drop events are getting fired when Windows scaling is other than 100% even though they shouldn't be firing.

Check out [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4aq1ek) example, and try to drag "blue" rectangle over itself (just drag, move a little bit downwards and drop). If Windows scaling is set to 100% (browser zoom is 100% as well) then one event is fired (`dragEnter`) as expected (check the console). But, if Windows scaling is set to 125% (but browser zoom is still 100%) then three events are fired (two `dragEnter` and one `dragLeave`), and I expected only one event to be fired since the element was dragged and dropped on itself (as it was the case with 100% scale level).

It could be that since this is Windows zoom (and not browser's zoom) the left ("lightred") rectangle is larger that it appears, and it goes below right rectangle, and events are propagated to it, although I couldn't prove that since all elements have correct size in the inspector.

This doesn't seem to be happening in latest Firefox, IE or Edge.

Does anyone know why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Adding console.log(event.target.className), in your event handlers might make it easier to see what's going on. I see multiple events firing at any scaling in Chromium 69.

Comment: The origin element should fire the dragstart and dragend handlers. And the destination element should fire the dragover and drop handlers. My advise to you is to get one-way drag and drop succeeding before tackling bi-directional drag and drop.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments, adding `className` confirmed that events are fired incorrectly (but I kinda already guessed that :) ). I don't use Chromium, but this is a simple layout and multiple events shouldn't be firing, wouldn't you agree?
I didn't understand the second comment, I know what events are firing on drag and drop, and I got one-way to work but I also need this bi-directional to work as well... Maybe you could clarify what you meant by that comment?
Again, thank you for your interest, any comment or help is welcome, I'm stuck on this for couple of days now, going crazy. :D

Comment: dragging blue div is calling drop event of 1st div, we can provide width in px (:host) its working for first few drag events on blue div but not recursively

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did `console.log` for drop events and none of the `drop` events for _left_ (lightred) rectangle occur when we drag _right_ (blue) rectangle. Also, setting fixed width on `:host` does not comply with my requirements, so that's no go.

Comment: I tried your example on Safari on a Mac, and it generated three events about 1 in every four or five tries.  I didn't look in detail, but guessing its probably real observations.  Not sure why it's causing you a problem, and what you want to fix?  If it detects an in and out and in, why is that a problem?  Certainly behavior you could anticipate from a human doing the dragging?  At any rate, I doubt windows scaling is the culprit.

Comment: Hi. The problem is that, in my real app, indicator (black line) is displayed when user starts dragging the element, and these three events make the line flicker (the line is displayed on `dragEnter` event and hidden on `dragLeave` event, and this flicker is quite noticeable). What's surprising here is that both `divs` are next to each other in layout yet `dnd` behaves like first one is somehow _behind_ the second one. I could solve my problem in another way but this issue still remains. Anyways, thank you for your comment and keep up the good work. :)

Comment: Could you post code that reproduces the issue? Not everyone can read white on black text that you used in the external website for the code

Answer (score 1):

There are instances where a website has drag-and-drop features that will not work inside the Google Chrome browser.

**Fixing Drag-and-Drop**

1. Enter the following into the Google Chrome Top search bar.
   Chrome Flags: chrome://flags/
2. Type `Touch` into the search bar and set the following options to `Enabled`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The more I look at this problem, the more it seems the Chromium issue. Some days ago I posted a question, then I wanted to set up a bounty for it, and then I found your one, and I believe they are interrelated: [Subpixel scroll issue, can't set scrollTop properly on Chrome 69](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470549/subpixel-scroll-issue-cant-set-scrolltop-properly-on-chrome-69).

There are some bug reports in Chromium issue tracker related to scale-rounding problem: [link 1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=689096), [link 2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=875726)... I also created my own bug: [link 3](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=890345#c1). There should be more information but it takes too much time to research. I think we may join efforts and draw more attention to the problem, and for example if it's Chromium responsibility, to help them with clarification and prioritisation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Version 76.0.3809.100 (64-Bit).

And I offset the image to compensate for the strange offset that I get in your stackbliz example too.

But with scaling 200% I need to multiply my calculated dragImage offset by 4 !!!

On 300% it's at 9
On 350% it's at 12.25

Do you see the pattern ???!

I'm afraid of my hack/fix for this problem. Not sure if it's just on windows, if it's just desktop. But for now I guess I will have to do window.devicePixelRatio^2 so I can continue my work.