# Subpixel scroll issue, can't set scrollTop properly on Chrome 69

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, zooming, scrolltop

I'm trying to set `scrollTop` property of some DOM element programmatically and I have weird behaviour that breaks my tests in some specific environment. I created minimal repro ([the link](https://jsfiddle.net/dhilt/mo4zveka/25/))

**HTML**

```
<div id=viewport><div id=content></div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#viewport {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 20px;
}
#content {
  height: 150px;
}
```

**JS**

```
const viewport = document.getElementById("viewport");
viewport.scrollTop = 75;
console.log(viewport.scrollTop);
```

The result of the script is broken on **Chrome 69.0.3497.100** running on **Win 10 Pro**. It is `74.4000015258789` instead of `75`. It works properly on the same **Chrome** version on **Mac** and even on **Win 10** Home running under VirtualBox. **Firefox** and **Edge** also have no such an issue.

I know it looks very strange, but what could it be? Can anyone confirm this problem? And could it be fixed in some way to make sure that the result of the `scrollTop` assignment is exactly I want it to be?

---

**Update**. Thanks to @khajjit, I was able to reproduce the issue on my Mac machine and got `74.66666412353516` on 75% zoom out and 150% zoom in. 80% gives `75`, 90% -- `74.44444274902344`, 110% -- `74.54545593261719` etc (I updated [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhilt/mo4zveka/25/) to show the results table). So the issue does not relate to OS. But it looks like the Chrome only issue. Firefox and Edge return 75 at any scale.

**Update 2**. Scaling the screen resolution at the OS layer also affects the situation. That was the case of Win 10 Pro described above; it had 125% OS scaling.

So the practical part of the question is how to overcome Chrome scaling rounding issues to be able to set `scrollTop` precisely?

---

**Update 3**. Chromium Dev [confirmed that this is a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=890345#c6):

> This issue is because Chrome does not fully support fractional scroll
>   offset.

So if someone is interested in this problem resolving, please follow [the link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=890345) and star the issue on the Chromium end.

Comment: i got 75 .chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) running on windows10

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be related to the resolution of the monitor.
I have a resolution of 1920x1080 and with a scale of 100% the result is 75.
But if you set 75% or 150%, the result will be 74.66666412353516.
Or say 25%, the result will be exactly 74.

---

I don't have any exact answer as to what it might be related to, but I think this little research might lead to the right path.